# UIImage mirroring acting weird

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mirror

I have a button that mirrors an image horizontally in an imageView. This means if it was an of me holding up my left hand, after clicking the button, it would seem like a picture of me holding up my right hand. The code executed by the button is show below.

Can someone explain why clicking the button the first time, mirrors the image correctly, but clicking it consecutive times does not result in it mirroring itself back and forth (nothing happens).

```
-(IBAction)mirrorImage3 {
    UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage scale:imageView.image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    imageView.image = flippedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation is a property of the `UIImage`, not an instruction how to modify the `CGImage`. You'll have to alternate between `UIImageOrientationUpMirrored` and `UIImageOrientationUp`.

Comment: What is the relationship between UIImage and CGImage? I understand CGImage is a property of UIImage. What I'm trying to achieve is the mirror the image (done), and save it to the phones library. I'm not sure I will be saving the "UIImage" or the "CGImage".

Comment: In this case, UIImage wraps a CGImage and adds orientation information. You'll save the UIImage to the camera roll.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that the following will happen in sequence, imagine an image which reads "AB" from left to right.  
(1) I flip the UIImage to read "BA". The UIImage will display as "BA" however the underlying CGImage that it wraps still reads "AB".  
(2) I save the image to the library.  
(3) I load up that image from the library into a new UIImage variable.  
(4) Both new UIImage and its underlying CGImage will read "BA"?     

Just trying to understand how I can also change or reinitialize the CGImage with a new image.

Comment: I believe that at step (4) you'll have the same CGImage as you originally did; I think only the UIImage is flipped. This depends on how you get the image into the camera roll, though; some of those methods might actually modify the CGImage.